# Save/open SharePoint Library files from Windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, xaml, rest, sharepoint-2013, windows

I am trying to save a local XML file to a SharePoint 2013 Library. Since Windows 8 apps (XAML) do not allow me to use the Microsoft.SharePoint.client.dll, I have been looking into the SP Rest API but have not found any documentation on how to save/open files. Any direction on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Share .NET](http://www.independentsoft.com/share) works with Windows 8 apps. I think it is possible to get it as portable class library too.